# What should i do to learn django-ninja

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-ninja

I am a beginner in programming, I'm trying to learn Django-ninja but I'm confused, what should I learn first, I know some basics of python. Will I need to learn Django first? I will be thankful if anyone have a map learn that leads to Django-ninja

Answer (score -1, accepted):

yes, to learn django-ninja you need first to learn django and have a look at django rest framework which has tutorials about API, then checkout pydantic, django-ninja depends on pydantic.

Comment: do you have any tutorial that can help ?

Comment: django tutorial - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/intro/tutorial01/
django rest framework - https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/
pydantic - https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/

Try to find these things on your own sometimes, google is your friend.

Answer (score -1):

You may learn FastAPI after Django. Ninja based on FastAPI